# How can I add a `loading...` icon to jQuery UI's autocomplete widget

Tags: javascript, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to modify [jQuery's autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to have the input's background color change while the script is searching for suggestions. Here is my attempt (or have a look at [my attempt on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/hbP7N/)):

**html**

```
<label for="numbers">Numbers: </label>
<input id="numbers" />
```

**javascript**

```
var numbers = [],
    nb = 10000,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < nb; i += 1) {
    numbers.push(i.toString());
}

function color (color) {
    $('#numbers').css({
        background: color
    });
}

$("#numbers").autocomplete({
    source: numbers,
    search: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('search event fired');
        color("red");
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('open event fired');
        color("green");
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('close event fired');
        color("white");
    }
});
```

As you can see, I'm logging the `search`, `open` and `close` events so I can see when they are fired.

As expected, typing in `5` (an existing value) fires the `search` event and logs the corresponding message, and, a few seconds later, fires the `open` event and logs its corresponding message. Since I put 10000 entries in there, there is a noticeable delay between the `search` event and the `open` event (something like 1 second).

What baffles me is that when the log message associated to the `search` event appears, it is not followed by the background color changing to red as should be expected. Instead, it remains white until the `open` event occurs, then becomes green (as expected after the open event). If, however, I type in `a` (a non-existing value), the background color goes red without problem (notice the open event never occurs in this case because no corresponding value is found). What's happening here?

For the curious, I'm ultimately trying to have a little `loading` icon appear while the search is underway (a feature which I am surprised isn't shipped with the widget out of the box). The background color change is a first step in that direction.

**UPDATE**

I made [another attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/TMMHE/1/) which shows that the instruction following `console.log` is indeed called, but the visual effects appear only much later. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$("#numbers").autocomplete({
    source: numbers,
    search: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('search event fired');
        $('#numbers').css({
            marginTop: "5em"
        });
        console.log('search callback done');
    }
});
```

If you try it out, you'll see that both messages are logged before the field is displaced by the addition of a top margin. Somehow, the margin is added at the right time, but the page is not being redrawn at the right time...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843054/jquery-ui-autocomplete-ui-autocomplete-loading

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489607/jquery-autocomplete-how-to-show-an-animated-gif

Comment: @user1477388 Neither of these links has proved helpful. Was this what you had in mind? http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/FTP8s/

Comment: See my answer below please

Answer (score 1):

So, have you tried this?

```
$("#numbers").autocomplete({
    source: numbers,
    search: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('search event fired');
        $(this).addClass('working');
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('open event fired');
        color("green");
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('close event fired');
        color("white");
    }
});
```

That should add a class to your textbox.  Just add a CSS style called "working" with background property of red.

Ref.  [jQuery autocomplete: How to show an animated gif loading image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489607/jquery-autocomplete-how-to-show-an-animated-gif)

Comment: Really, you shouldn't need any code since the `.ui-autocomplete-loading` class gets applied automatically while the loading is taking place.  However, I think there is a bug where it won't show the style.  Ref. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-problem-styling-of-ui-autocomplete-loading-not-working

Comment: Yes, I saw that thread, but I never found out how to do the search asynchronously whilst using a static list. There seems to be nothing about it in the documentation...

Comment: Sorry I can't help.  If you think not being async is the problem, try adding your static values to a server and call them via ajax.

Comment: Looks like it could be paused because javascript is a single-threaded language.  They are using a SetTimeout() which pauses the execution...  I would try using `source: function(request, response) {` and try to execute your change there before you return the response.

Comment: I am surprised to see the source callback being called on every query. However, it doesn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/VgmE5/

Comment: I think your next best bet is to try playing with the actual jQuery UI method for "search" as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5677466/1477388 It calls a timeout which is what I think is preventing the DOM from being effected by the style.

Comment: I really don't see the relation between that timeout and my problem as  all `console.log` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: it's not your fault :) What's happening, is that the painting of the browsers is basically stalled because of the autocomplete plugin being **extemely** slow.

To identify how slow and why it's slow, you can use Chrome Devtool's timeline tab. While in frame mode, press record to see a graph like this:

[image: Screenshot of timeline in Devtools]

You'll see the yellow bars (Scripts) go way above the bar's outlines once you start entering input. This means the operations cannot be completed in time thus causing the browser to stall. You can view the stacktrace to determine what lines exactly are really slow. The problem is fixable though, but it will require quite some knowledge of the jquery-ui internals.

When working with this many options, frontend scripting may not suffice. You could look into a server-side search with ajax frontend so the heavy lifting is done by the server.

Comment: Are you saying that the scripting requires so much computing that the browser no longer has "time" to re-draw the screen to the the red background?

Comment: Yes. That's because the CSS is done in the 'painting' thread of the browser. Unfortunately, this is also the part of jquery-ui that's slowing down the page. It's stupid and to be honest, I'm surprised jquery-ui isn't written well enough to coop with this.

Comment: One more thing, I haven't done a performance comparison, but I've used http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation in the past and didn't run into any trouble. Depending on your needs, this might be a good option to look in to.